# How to convert org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.entity.RestNode to Spring Data Neo4j Node Entity

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using Spring Data for Neo4j to access Neo4j graph. I have a `UserRepository` with an annotated query as below:

```
package com.abc.graph.repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Query;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.NamedIndexRepository;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.RelationshipOperationsRepository;

import com.abc.graph.entity.User;

public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User>, NamedIndexRepository<User>,
        RelationshipOperationsRepository<User> {
    public User findById(String id);

    public Page<User> findByNameLike(String name, Pageable page);

    @Query("START user=node:User(id={0}) " +  
            "MATCH user-[:VISITS]->(location)<-[:VISITS]-(similar_user) " +
            "RETURN similar_user, collect(location) as locations, count(*) as count " + 
            "ORDER BY count desc ")
    public List<Map<String, Object>> findSimilarUsersByPlaceVisited(String userId);
}
```

What I am trying to retrieve from the graph is a list of users who have been to the similar places and for each user, what are the common places they have been to. The method will return a list of `Map<String, Object>`. Each map will contains key like `similar_user`, `locations` and `count`.

From debug statement I can see that `similar_user` is an instance of `org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.entity.RestNode`. Is there any way to convert it to my Spring Data node entity which is `com.abc.graph.entity.User`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it manually by using:

`template.createEntityFrom[Stored]State(userNode[,User.class)`

Or you define as result an `Iterable` or `Collection` of an interface annotated with `@MapResult` with getters for the three columns. It either automatically maps the getter names to result columns or you can provide a name to map to.

```
@MapResult
interface SimilarUser {

   @ResultColumn("count") int getCount();
   @ResultColumn("similar_user") User getUser();
   @ResultColumn("locations") Collection<Location> getLocations();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The `@MapResult` annotation works. However I'm getting this exception when invoking `getLocations()` method: `org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.QueryResultBuilder$1 cannot be cast to java.util.Collection` Any idea?

Comment: Hmm good point, can you use `@ResultColumn("locations") Iterable<Location> getLocations();`

Comment: I'm getting another exception when trying to call `next()` method of the `Iterator`: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot extract single value from Iterable with more than one elements.`